# Tests react component (context.router - undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jasmine, react-router, karma-runner

I am testing react component with chai + karma + enzyme.

```
mount(
<Provider store={configureStore(mockContext, null)}>
  <Component {...props} />
</Provider>
)
```

I am using in this component context.router.location. And i get error that this undefined. I try to pass context with the second parameter of mount like this:

```
mount(
<Provider store={configureStore(mockContext, null)}>
  <Component {...props} />
</Provider>,    
    { 
      context: {
        router: {
          location: { pathname: '' }
        }
      },
      childContextTypes: {
        router: React.PropTypes.object
      }
    })
```

How can pass context in my component?

```
"react-router": "^3.0.2",
"enzyme": "^2.3.0",
```

p.s. typescript:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `childContextTypes` as a separate object and not as a child of context as

```
mount(
    <Provider store={configureStore(mockContext, null)}>
       <Component {...props} />
    </Provider>,    
    { 
      context: {
        router: {
          location: { pathname: '' }
        }
      },
      childContextTypes: {
          router: React.PropTypes.object
      }

    })
```

Comment: sorry. My example is bad:( I am doing like you and i have a router - undefined.
Maybe i can somehow diferently do it?